# Parity older version force me to sync from scratch, how to fix this?

Tags: parity

I am using private Ethereum chain. I have sync my chain using `Parity/v1.7.0-beta`. Now I changed the `Parity` version back to `Parity/v1.6.10-stable`; but it gives following error:

```
Database was created with newer client version. Upgrade your client or delete DB and resync.
```

[Q] Without updating `Parity`, is there any way to prevent this error and continue sync from where the chain remained?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Not sure, you could try to export the blockchain to a file, reset the db and import the chain from the file.